# Apache CXF handle enum path variable error and return custom response

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cxf

I am having a path variable as an enum. Deployed on JBoss, a HTML error page with stacktraces is displayed if the value of `productType` is invalid. What I want to do is to handle this error and return a standard `GenericApiResponse` JSON object instead.

```
@Path("product")
@Produces({ APPLICATION_JSON })
public class ProductEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Path("/{productType}/info")
    public GenericApiResponse info(@PathParam("productType") ProductType productType) {
        // Get product info and return
    }


}
```

Enum class:

```
public enum ProductType {

    GLOBAL,
    INTERNAL

    public static ProductType fromString(String value) {
        for(ProductType t : ProductType.class.getEnumConstants()) {
            if(t.name().toLowerCase().equals(value)) {
                return t;
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidProductTypeException();
    }
}
```

HTML stacktrace (nothing useful)

```
JBWEB000071: root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.hasEntity()Z
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.convertFaultToResponse(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.convertFaultToResponse(JAXRSUtils.java:1516)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.convertExceptionToResponseIfPossible(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:261)
    org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:92)
    org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:211)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

So I tried to make my own `ExceptionMapper`, **only it does not work**. My class is never called, and the HTML error page is still showing.

**InvalidProductTypeExceptionMapper.java**

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class InvalidProductTypeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<InvalidProductTypeException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(InvalidProductTypeExceptione) {
        // This is never being called
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(new GenericApiResponse(ResultCode.INVALID_PARAMETERS))
                .build();
    }

}
```

**cxf.xml**

```
<jaxrs:providers>
    <bean class="com.my.mapper.InvalidProductTypeExceptionMapper "/>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

**My question: How can I handle such error and return a custom response?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think adding the `fromString` method to your enum class does anything in CXF.

To make the conversion, consider use ParamConverter and ParamConverterProvider:

```java
    public class ProductTypeConverter implements ParamConverter<ProductType> {

        @Override
        public ProductType fromString(String value) {
            // throw your exception here.
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(ProductType value) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Then add

```
    @Provider
    public class MyParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider{
        @Override
        public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
            if(rawType.equals(ProductType.class)) {
                return (ParamConverter<T>) new ProductTypeConverter();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Add the provider to your endpoint, in conjunction with your ExceptionMapper. It should get you the result you want.